# Rigorous derivation of entanglement entropy bound of MPS

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, tensor-network

I am working on a summer project and am trying to prove the Von Neumann entropy of an MPS is bounded by a constant to gain some introduction. While this easily follows if we start with the MPS being obtained from a Schmidt Decomposition, e.g. [What states are satisfying an entropic area law and why do they satisfy it? More specificly why do matrix product states satisfy it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60468/),
I am trying to show it using the general structure of the MPS itself.

I wrote down the reduced density matrix using the partial trace, but am stuck at $S = -Tr(\rho\log\rho)$. Is there some nice graphical or tensor method way to proceed?

[image]

Comment: Hint: The entropy is bounded by the log of the rank of rho. But what is wrong with the Schmidt decomposition?

Comment: Thanks! I understand that and yes, the Schmidt method proof is completely valid. I just thought such a way could (maybe?) make it easier to try and understand higher dimensional bounds like MERA etc.

Comment: In essence each bond of dimension D which you cut gives a summation index with D values. This means that the product of D you cut gives/bounds the total rank of the reduced density matrix, the log of which in turn bounds the entropy.